# How to say "gawker" in French?

Tags: traduction, anglais

Sorry I don't have much context, all I have is this definition from Wiktionary:

> gawker: Someone who gawks, someone who stares stupidly

How to translate this word to French?

(There might be several words if *gawker* has several meanings.)

Comment: Does a gawker always stare studidly at atuff, or is it just a one moment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Il peut signifier un *voyeurs* ou un *curieux*.
On pourrait utiliser le terme de *badaud* lorsqu'il désigne un observateur dans la rue.

Answer (score 2):

En langage familier cela peut aussi signifier *godiche* ou *grand dadais*
et s'il s'agit d'un verbe : *rester bouche bée*.

Comment: la ca n'a rien a voir..  godiche means an awkward/stupid person, grand dadais a tall klutz, and rester bouche bee to be speechless.  No notion of gawker in any of this.